# Query to get results with the grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table `Customers` with `fields id, name, rating, seller_id`.
The result of query

```
select seller_id, MAX(rating) 
from Customer 
group by seller_id
```

is the customers grouped by `seller_id` with max values of the rating. Like this:

```
seller_id  rating
2          17
3          20
4          17
```

How to modify this query to get customer's id additionally?
If I add `id` to `SELECT` I get an error, that I should add `id` to grouping. But I want only get above shown values with id specified. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: please post some sample Input and output data

Comment: Tag properly. MySQL and tsql don't go well together...

Comment: Why do you have a seller_id column in the customers table?

Comment: it is a foreign key for the customers table

Comment: to @jarlh . Thanks. Fixed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select t.id, t.seller_id, t.rating
from Customer c
join (
    select seller_id, MAX(rating) rating
    from Customer 
    group by seller_id
) x
on x.seller_id = c.seller_id
and x.rating = c.rating
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select c1.* from Customer c1 inner join 
(select seller_id, MAX(rating) as rating from Customer 
group by seller_id) c2 on c1.rating  = c2.rating
```

or

```
 SELECT c1.* FROM Customer b1 LEFT JOIN Customer c2
 ON (b1.seller_id = b2.seller_id  AND b1.rating > b2.br_created_date)
 WHERE b2.rating is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

SimarjeetSingh has a good answer. Just tweak a little more:

```
select c.customer_id, c.seller_id
from customer c
join (
  select seller_id, max(rating) max_rating
  from customer
  group by seller_id
) s 
  on c.seller_id = s.seller_id
  and c.rating = s.max_rating
```

This way you are comparing the seller_id and the maximum rating.

Answer (score 0):

**A dataset is divided into
groups using the GROUP BY clause.
The grouping attribute is common
key shared by members of each group.
The grouping attribute is usually a single
column but may be multiple columns or
an expression that cannot be based on
group functions. Note that only grouping
attributes and group functions are
permitted in the SELECT clause when using
GROUP BY.**

refer this
[Select EMP with max SAL from each DEPT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428473/select-emp-with-max-sal-from-each-dept)